# sudo -u username notify-send stuck

Tags: command-line, notify-osd, notify-send

here is my code:

```
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/rbs/ro_wemedia $ time sudo -u root notify-send 'prpr'

real    0m0.033s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.012s

roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/rbs/ro_wemedia $ time sudo -u roroco /usr/bin/notify-send "prpr"

real    0m6.044s
user    0m0.016s
sys 0m0.016s
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/rbs/ro_wemedia $ time /usr/bin/notify-send "prpr"

real    0m0.110s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.008s
```

see above output, when i use `sudo -u roroco notify-send 'prpr'`, the time is long, what cause it?

here is my notify-send version

```
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/rbs/ro_wemedia $ notify-send -v
notify-send 0.7.6
```

Answer (score 0):

solution: make sure 3 env vars exist

to me, it's

```
sudo -u roroco DISPLAY=:0.0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-L9d2ku9CfF" XAUTHORITY=/home/roroco/.Xauthority notify-send 'prpr'
```

you can get env var value with `echo $env-name`